# Javascript - How to remove all items with a particular ID and its associated items? Then its associated items and its subsequent items (recursion?)

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I am having some difficulties in what the best way to go about this is.

Example below:

```js
const arr = [{
  parentId: 1,
  children: [
    { childId: 11 },
    { childId: 21 },
    { childId: 31 },
  ]
}, {
  parentId: 31,
  children: [
    { childId: 111 },
    { childId: 211 },
    { childId: 311 },
  ]
}, {
  parentId: 7,
  children: [
    { childId: 711 },
    { childId: 721 },
    { childId: 731 },
  ]
}, {
  parentId: 311,
  children: [
    { childId: 3111 },
    { childId: 3211 },
    { childId: 3311 },
  ]
}]
```

So, say I want to remove parentId = 1 then I would like to remove all its assoicated children and if the associated children also is a parentId then their subsequent children as well. Therefore, parentIds 11, 21, 31. 31 is a parentId so remove its childIds - 111, 211 and 311. 311 is a parentId so remove its childIds. No childIds as parentIds fr 311 so we can stop there.

Please if anyone is able to advise best way to go about it. I was thinking recursion but the examples I have seen is more for nested arrays rather than children then separate arrays and repeat the process.

So we would be left with

```
[{
  parentId: 7,
  children: [
    { childId: 711 },
    { childId: 721 },
    { childId: 731 },
  ]
}]
```

Answer (score 2):

You need no *recursion*, because of the sorted and flat data and you could filter with a closure over a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) where all `childId` are collected.

```js
const
    remove = (data, id) => data.filter((s => o => {
        if (!s.has(o.parentId)) return true;
        o.children.forEach(({ childId }) => s.add(childId));
    })(new Set([id]))),
    data = [{ parentId: 1, children: [{ childId: 11 }, { childId: 21 }, { childId: 31 }] }, { parentId: 31, children: [{ childId: 111 }, { childId: 211 }, { childId: 311 }] }, { parentId: 7, children: [{ childId: 711 }, { childId: 721 }, { childId: 731 }] }, { parentId: 311, children: [{  childId: 3111 }, { childId: 3211 }, { childId: 3311 }] }],
    result = remove(data, 1);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to have a queue of ids-to-delete, delete an id on the top of the queue and append all dependent ids. For convenience, let's also convert your array to a map id->object:

```js
const arr=[{parentId:1,children:[{childId:11},{childId:21},{childId:31}]},{parentId:31,children:[{childId:111},{childId:211},{childId:311}]},{parentId:7,children:[{childId:711},{childId:721},{childId:731}]},{parentId:311,children:[{childId:3111},{childId:3211},{childId:3311}]}]

//

let m = new Map(arr.map(o => [o.parentId, o]))
let remove = [1]

while (remove.length > 0) {
    let id = remove.shift()
    let obj = m.get(id)
    if (obj) {
        console.log('debug: deleting', id)
        m.delete(id)

        remove.push(...obj.children.map(c => c.childId))
    }
}

let result = [...m.values()]
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

A possibility using recursion and the [Ramda.js](https://ramdajs.com) library:

```js
import * as R from 'ramda'

const initialArr = [
  { parentId: 1, children: [{ childId: 11 }, { childId: 21 }, { childId: 31 }] }, 
  { parentId: 31, children: [{ childId: 111 }, { childId: 211 }, { childId: 311 }] }, 
  { parentId: 7, children: [{ childId: 711 }, { childId: 721 }, { childId: 731 }] }, 
  { parentId: 311, children: [{ childId: 3111 }, { childId: 3211 }, { childId: 3311 }] }
]

const removeDesc = (id,arr) => R.pipe(
  R.find(R.propEq("parentId",id)),            // find parent
  R.propOr([],"children"),                    // handle zero case  
  R.pluck("childId"),                         // find the children  
  R.reduce(R.flip(removeDesc), arr),          // recurse the children
  R.reject(R.propEq("parentId", id))          // then remove the parent
)(arr)

console.log( JSON.stringify( removeDesc(1,initialArr) ) )   
// [{"parentId":7,"children":[{"childId":711},{"childId":721},{"childId":731}]}]
```

Using a functional-programming style like this I find makes the code easier to follow (in the long-run!). It tends to encourage using immutable data structures too, so there's less risk of unintended consequences through modification. It's not necessarily the most efficient at run-time though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion to solve this.

```js
const arr=[{parentId:1,children:[{childId:11},{childId:21},{childId:31}]},{parentId:31,children:[{childId:111},{childId:211},{childId:311}]},{parentId:7,children:[{childId:711},{childId:721},{childId:731}]},{parentId:311,children:[{childId:3111},{childId:3211},{childId:3311}]}];

function myReduce(inputArr, key) {
  for (let [i, arrElem] of inputArr.entries()) {
    if (arrElem.parentId && arrElem.parentId === key) {
      const childElem = arrElem.children;
      if (childElem.length) {
        for (let child of childElem) {
          myReduce(inputArr, child.childId);
        }
      }
      inputArr.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
  return inputArr;
}

const newArr = myReduce(arr, 1);
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(newArr, null, 2);
```

```html
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach with `lodash` and recursion:

```js
const arr = [{
  parentId: 1,
  children: [
    { childId: 11 },
    { childId: 21 },
    { childId: 31 },
  ]
}, {
  parentId: 31,
  children: [
    { childId: 111 },
    { childId: 211 },
    { childId: 311 },
  ]
}, {
  parentId: 7,
  children: [
    { childId: 711 },
    { childId: 721 },
    { childId: 731 },
  ]
}, {
  parentId: 311,
  children: [
    { childId: 3111 },
    { childId: 3211 },
    { childId: 3311 },
  ]
}]

const removeByParentId = (arr, parentId) => {
  const parent = _.find(arr, { parentId });
  if (!parent) return arr;
  
  let updatedArr = _.reject(arr, { parentId });
  parent.children.forEach(child => {
    updatedArr = removeByParentId(updatedArr, child.childId);
  });

  return updatedArr;
};

const outputArr = removeByParentId(arr, 1);

console.log(outputArr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```